# How to show vets near user location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How can I show the vets and pet shops near the user location I used the api comes from google_maps activity maybe that could be the problem I just wanted to point out.
here what I tryed but the app crashes in the logchat it shows two line I'm gone mark it with stairs for you thanks for trying to help.

```
public class Harita extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityHaritaBinding binding;
private Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_harita);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    **PlacesSearchResult[] placesSearchResults = new NearbySearch().run().results;

    Log.e("response1Tag", placesSearchResults[0].toString());
    Log.e("response2Tag", placesSearchResults[1].toString());

    double lat1 = placesSearchResults[0].geometry.location.lat;
    double lng1 = placesSearchResults[0].geometry.location.lng;

    double lat2 = placesSearchResults[1].geometry.location.lat;
    double lng2 = placesSearchResults[1].geometry.location.lng;

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2, lng2)));

    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(14.0f);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));
}
```

}

```
public class NearbySearch {
public PlacesSearchResponse run(){
    PlacesSearchResponse request = new PlacesSearchResponse();
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
            .apiKey("MY_APİ")
            **.build();
    LatLng location = new LatLng(-33.8670522, 151.1957362);

    try {
        request = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, location)
                .radius(5000)
                .rankby(RankBy.PROMINENCE)
                .keyword("cruise")
                .language("en")
                .type(PlaceType.VETERINARY_CARE)
                .await();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return request;
    }
}
```

}
here is the error log

```
2021-07-24 21:05:38.747 8645-8645/com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi, PID: 8645
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi/com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi.Harita}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):6)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):30)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):22)
    at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@212418068@21.24.18 (100700-0):4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zze.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzav.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzav.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:9)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1731)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:103)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
2021-07-24 21:05:38.748 8645-8645/com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2771)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:380)
    at com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi.Harita.onCreate(Harita.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: please attach error log and add what you actually expecting

Comment: @devReddit I edited error log and I'm expecting to show vets near user location

Comment: Error logs shows ` API key not found.` make sure you added your API key correctly to your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
```

`okhttp3` may not have support for SDK INT 30. You can give a try by downgrading to SDK INT 28.

However, for current case, add an explicit dependency on OkHttp latest version, whatever is newest exists now. This should solve the problem.

Comment: app crashes again different reason this time    2021-07-24 17:22:49.232 5706-5706/com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sahin.evcilhayvanrehberi, PID: 5706
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array

Comment: please add the details error log updating the question

Comment: have you generated the api_key and checked the manifest file?